# Product URL is not saving in URL Rewrite?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

Product URL is not saving in URL Rewrites and i am getting product URL is like this

https://vitalticks.in/catalog/product/view/id/3688/s/meta-paper-points-color-coded-and-length-marked/category/292/

Thanks
Somu N

Comment: try to generate url rewrite..

Comment: how can i do this one ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to regenerate url rewrite :-**

[elgentos
/
regenerate-catalog-urls](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls)

Comment: if i use above Module website is not loading

Comment: try to indexer:reinde

Answer (score 0):

instead of `getProcuctUrl()`
Try this

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
$url = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
```